# $4$ fair dice are rolled ,where each dice has $m$-sides numbered $1$ to $m$ inclusive.

Tags: combinatorics

How many different ways can two of the dice add up to $3$?
The question is that I don't know the meaning of the 'ways'. Do the 'ways' mean 'event' or the 'way'?
For 'event':

- Case 1: $2\;1\;1\;1$ $(^4_1)$
- Case 2: $2\;2\;1\;1$ $(^4_2)$
- Case 3: $2\;2\;2\;1$ $(^4_1)$
- Case 4: $2\;1\;p\;p$ $(m-2)(^4_2)(^2_1)$
- Case 5: $2\;2\;1\;p$ $(m-2)(^4_2)(^2_1)$
- Case 6: $2\;1\;1\;p$ $(m-2)(^4_2)(^2_1)$
- Case 7: $2\;1\;p\;q\;(p\neq q)$ $(^{m-2}_2)(^4_3)(^3_2)(^2_1)(^1_1)$

and sum them up.
For 'way': Just omit the permutation.
Which answer is right? Or is there any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: I think the reasonable way to interpret 'ways' is that there are a total of $m^4$ ways the four dice can come up. For the question how many ways can two of the dice add up to $3$ I used the in-and-out formula and I got $$m^4-2(m-1)^4+(m-2)^4=12m^2-24m+14.$$

Comment: Re bof's comment/answer, see [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).